# Spring Data MongoDB - Criteria API OrOperator is not working properly

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm facing Spring Data MongoDB Criteria API `orOperator` problem.

Here's query result for irregular verbs: (**Terminal output**)

```
> db.verb.find({'v2':'wrote'});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5161a8adba8c6390849da453"), "v1" : "write", "v2" : "wrote", "v3" : "written" }
```

And I query verbs by their `v1` or `v2` values using **Spring Data MongoDB Criteria API**:

```
Criteria criteriaV1 = Criteria.where("v1").is(verb);
Criteria criteriaV2 = Criteria.where("v2").is(verb);
Query query = new Query(criteriaV1.orOperator(criteriaV2));
List<Verb> verbList = mongoTemplate.find(query, Verb.class)
```

But unfortunately `verbList` doesn't have any item.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As far as I remember in order to use orOperator you should do:

```
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().orOperator(criteriaV1,criteriaV2));
```

Comment: thanks for your help; after I inspect application logs, I see that first parameter is used like a AND criteria. So the solution is using new instance of Criteria like you wrote or adding an always true condition.

Comment: How can we use multiple orOperator to search for multiple criterias ?

Comment: operator methods take any amount of paramters

Answer (score 4):

We need explicitly specify a new criteria with OR condition - try with below example

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("field1").is(val1).
                .andOperator(new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("field2").is(filterVal),
                        Criteria.where("field3").is(filterVal)));
```