# OrOperator in MongoTemplate not returning values?

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am working on Spring MVC with MongoDB.
I have added criteria for some fields with orOperator, Each Fields has value in database, but List returning is Empty.

```
criteriaQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("First_Name").is(docName.trim())
.orOperator(Criteria.where("Middle_Name").is(docName.trim())
.orOperator(Criteria.where("Last_Name").is(docName.trim()))));
```

Query printing in console is

```
 Query: { "First_Name" : "ESTHER" , "$or" : [ { "Middle_Name" : "ESTHER" , "$or" : [ { "Last_Name" : "ESTHER"}]}]}, Fields: null, Sort: null
```

I tried the Like query, but that also results the same

```
 criteriaQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("First_Name").regex(docName)
.orOperator(Criteria.where("Middle_Name").regex(docName))
    .orOperator(Criteria.where("Last_Name").regex(docName)));
```

Mongo Query

```
db.doctor_details.find({  "$or" : {"First_Name" : { "$regex" : "ESTHER"} }, "$or" : [ { "Middle_Name" : { "$regex" : "ESTHER"} , "$or" : [ { "Last_Name" : { "$regex" : "ESTHER"}}]}]})
```

Help me to get the result, I dont know where my code goes wrong. Help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Because that should be `.orOperator(Criteria.where("Middle_Name").is(docName.trim(), Criteria.where("Last_Name").is(docName.trim())` As should be evidenced from the serialization obtained. `$or` needs to be a `List` of `Criteria` and not multiple constructs.

Comment: Still it returns empty

Comment: Do you actually have a document that matches? Note that you are actually asking for something to be present in either field with that exact uppercase value ( or at least part of a word matching ). So it's not going to match if the case is different unless you actually ask it to in the regular expression.

Comment: By changing the code to criteriaQuery.addCriteria( new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("First_Name").is(docName.trim()),Criteria.where("Middle_Name").is(docName.trim()), Criteria.where("Last_Name").is(docName.trim())));  , this gave me the result, but how can i add Like within orOperator

Comment: What do you mean "within"? Your question asks for an `$or` to be presented for `First_Name`, `Middle_Name` or `Last_Name`. That is what the corrected syntax is doing for you. If you mean to do something else then it is not coming across clearly in your question and that could therefore do with some revision.

Comment: Yup Got you , Actually I asked how to use Like inside the or criertia..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringData regex not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956516/springdata-regex-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Use `criteriaQuery.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(
                Criteria.where("First_Name").regex(docName),
                Criteria.where("Middle_Name").regex(docName),
                Criteria.where("Last_Name").regex(docName)
                )
        );`  Please take a look at dupe for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember in order to use orOperator you should do:

```
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().orOperator(criteriaV1,criteriaV2));
```

[it is based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866175/spring-data-mongodb-criteria-api-oroperator-is-not-working-properly)